# How to attach timeline screenshot in add notes for facebook app review?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have submitted my android app on Facebook for review. But after reviewing from Facebook, they told that i have to add timeline screenshot in add note section of publish action. [image]

Now in notes section of publish actions, i didn't find any way of attaching screenshot of my timeline.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit apk for review again.Along with it you have to attache time line screen shot means when you sharing on facebook some thing with which account you share on facebook go to its profile page and screen shot containing that sharing portion you need to attach with your apk in your next submission.